# Python adding column with condition not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to add a column based on a condition like

```
for i in range(len(data) - 1):
    a = data.loc[i, 'column1']
    b = data.loc[i+1, 'column1']
    if a == b:
        data['column2'] = 1
    else:
        data['column2'] = 0
```

This shows no error and the new column has been created, however the logic does not work, the new column is filled with 0 regardless of the logic. I have checked if `a == b` by printing the values for `a` and `b`  with `a == b` and the result is as I expected. I am not sure why that is?
Note that the reason why I am using if statements is because my logic involves if and, else if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the if statement, it should be `data.loc[i,'column2']` this way it will right in the value at that location